# How to instantiate a checkbox in the form constructor in Django?

Tags: django, forms, checkbox

Here is my code:

models.py

```
class CheckModel(models.Model):
    a = models.BooleanField()
    b = models.BooleanField()
```

forms.py

```
class CheckForm(forms.Form):
    CHOICES = (('a', 'A',), ('b', 'B'))
    check_form= forms.MultipleChoiceField(required=False,
                                                   choices=CHOICES,
                                                   widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
                                                   label='')
```

views.py

```
settings = CheckModel.objects.get(pk=1)
a = settings.a
b = settings.b

if request.method == 'GET':
    form = CheckForm(initial = {'a': a, 'b': b}) # <-- doesn't check or uncheck the boxes on GET
```

The last code is my problem. How do I instantiate a form with checkboxes checked or unchecked from variables that I get from the database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The field is called `check_form`, not `a` or `b; those are the values of that field. So you can just do:

```
form = CheckForm(initial = {'check_form': ['a', 'b']})
```

However if you're instantiating forms with data from the database, you would be better off using a ModelForm and passing in the `instance` parameter on initialization.